# How to write this mysql where clause?

Tags: mysql

I have a field `date_purchased` and `date_ordered` which are datetime fields. Now I need to fetch the record if the product was purchased after order, and if the puchase was 2 days earlier or 7 days after order:

```
if(date_purchased>date_ordered)
{
    if(date_purchased>(today-2) or date_puchased<(date_ordered+7))
}
```

Basically, how do I translate the above code to mysql where condition( nested and/or)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DATE_SUB()` and `DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to add days to a datetime field.  The two date comparisons are enclosed in `()` as a single component to the `AND`.

```
WHERE
  date_purchased > date_ordered
  AND (
    date_purchased > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
    OR date_purchased  < DATE_ADD(date_ordered, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  )
```

**Note** If these are `DATETIME` fields rather than `DATE` fields, you may want to strip off the time portion with `DATE()` so that the day comparisons start at the beginning of the day, rather than some 24 hour interval from the current time.  This also means using `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()` to get today's date rather than a timestamp.

```
WHERE
  date_purchased > date_ordered
  AND (
    DATE(date_purchased) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) 
    OR DATE(date_purchased)  < DATE_ADD(DATE(date_ordered), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot:

However what if I need to add another check in there like "email='test@test.com AND <date check>'"

Comment: @aoi Then it just becomes another `AND`, added before or after like `WHERE datecheck1 AND (datechecks2) AND email = 'addr@examplelcom'`

Answer (score 0):

Use the BETWEEN operator to select the interval.

WHERE d BETWEEN *date-2 AND *date+7

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE date_purchased > date_ordered
    AND (DATE_DIFF(date_purchased, date_ordered) > 2
    OR DATE_DIFF(date_purchased, date_ordered) < -7)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that miss indexes on date_purchased and date_ordered fields?